# Magnetic field from displacement currents in a capacitor, and an applied exterior magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, capacitance, classical-electrodynamics

[image]

If an exterior magnetic field ($B$) is applied to oppose or support the magnetic field produced by the displacement currents ($B_D$), what would happen to the electric field within the gap? And the capacitor in general?

**Diagram:**
[image]

The exterior magnetic field($B$)is not uniform, as indicated, also varying with time.

[image]

Comment: How would that external magnetic field be applied?

Comment: Added a diagram to the question, hope that clarifies.  If you meant by what's causing the magnetic field? Could be anything(From magnet, solenoid, single wire).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the only practical way to produce a magnetic field supporting or opposing the magnetic field produced by the displacement current (presumably, in all points in space), is to generate another current spatially aligned with the original current and flowing in the same or the opposite direction.

The spatial alignment means that this current will have to flow in the leads of the capacitor and, therefore, either increase or decrease the rate of its charging and discharging and, with it, its electric field.

Comment: What if the field was covering "encompassing" the whole capacitor's interior? And it's also not uniform(added a diagram in the question) wouldn't it cause and effect? Also, I'm very curious as to why the spatial alignment has to be with the leads/plate to plate (i.e within the capacitor).

Comment: @e.d.m The magnetic field you drew has completely different shape/direction than the field produced by displacement current, so it won't specifically support or oppose it, therefore, we can consider its effect on the electric field independently of the effect of the magnetic field due to displacement current. If this new field is changing, it will produce circular electric field in the plane of the page, which will just superimpose on the electric field due to the displacement current, i.e., the electric field at any given point will be a sum of the two fields.

Comment: @e.d.m The requirement for spatial alignment would be necessary if you wanted to scale the existing field up or down (to the extent that it could be completely canceled) without changing its shape.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. What's mostly confusing is the consequences; firstly, if the exterior magnetic field was aligned and opposing the displacement current's magnetic field, or if the exterior magnetic field was varying and producing an electric field that of which opposes the electric field within the capacitor, how would that effect the capacitance or charging/discharge of a capacitor. Besides spatially aligning.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how my diagram does not have the magnetic fields opposing & supporting at certain points. If we say that the blue arrows is the $E$ and the $B_d$ curls around it, then the right side is being opposed($B_d$ - $B$)while the left side is being supported ($B_d$ + $B$).

Comment: I added another diagram to clarify it further. Thanks again!

Comment: @e.d.m If you somehow created a magnetic field aligned, more or less, with the magnetic field produced by the a displacement current, it would induce 
a current into the leads feeding the capacitor and therefore change the current and the electric field in the gap.

Comment: If I defined the area to be the separation gap, and modeled a change in B($B_f$ > $B_i$) from vector analysis of the induced $E$ I keep imagining the net-electric field is zero, image: https://i.imgur.com/77f4Cxk.jpg , leading to no change for the capacitor.

Comment: @e.d.m If the external magnetic field is limited to the gap area (as in your last picture)  and directed as shown there, i.e., not specifically supporting or opposing the magnetic field associated with the displacement current, I agree with your conclusion that the electric field it induces should not affect the operation of the capacitor.

Comment: V.F, I was reviewing this whole discussion, and reached to this conclusion if you can weigh in: If the displacement current's magnetic field $B_d$ was increasing due to $B_d$'s alignment to $B$($∴$ $B$ + $B_d$) that could either charge or discharge the capacitor faster, depending on the direction of $I_d$. Since it would either help increase/decrease the change of electric field.

Comment: @e.d.m I think so. Of course, the external magnetic field would have to be in sync with the normal charge/discharge current - otherwise the effect of the external field would change with time, i.e., sometimes it would support the normal current and sometimes it would oppose it.