# EM Lorentz force field flux in the air gap of a parallel plates charging capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, condensed-matter, material-science, magnetostatics

For a charging/discharging capacitor, simultaneously to the electric field created by the [displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) during charge/discharge cycle, a magnetic field is also generated in the area inside the air gap of the capacitor as well as in the area around the capacitor as shown:

[image: E and B field components in a charging capacitor]

image credits: Addison Wesley Longman, Inc. (The image is taken from this link: [Magnetic field from displacement currents in a capacitor, and an applied exterior magneticfield](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421158/magnetic-field-from-displacement-currents-in-a-capacitor-and-an-applied-exterio))

We assume that in the area around the capacitor there is negligible fringing $E$ (i.e. capacitor plates very close together) field therefore there is only the magnetic concentric rings around the capacitor of the generated $B$ field due to the displacement current during charge or discharge of the capacitor (i.e. the capacitor charged with a manual switch from 0V to +V or discharged from +V to 0V).

We position in the air gap of the capacitor an acrylic thin board which will act as the dielectric of the capacitor and which we have previously sprinkled with **rusted (iron oxide dielectric) iron filings**. Because the oxidized dielectric surface layer of the iron filings they can act as EM sensors sensing both electric and magnetic field components inside the air gap of a charging or discharging capacitor. Thus, our iron fillings sensors can both electrostatically charged as well as magnetized in the same time. We tap the acrylic board with our finger during charge of the capacitor or discharge to overcome any mass inertia of the iron filings and help them to align to the composite field inside the air gap of the charging/discharging capacitor.

For the field imprint obtained with the iron filings outside and around the capacitor (i.e. assuming there is no electric field outside the capacitor) I believe there is no doubt that it will form a concentric rings field geometric structure.

**My problem is, what form will have the field imprint from the rusted iron filings inside the capacitor's air gap?**

Each iron filing piece acts like a charge and would be subject (assuming that the iron filings have also gained some velocity by us tapping the acrylic board during charge) of the total EM [Lorentz interaction force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force):

$$
\mathbf{F}=q \mathbf{E}+q \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}
$$

and at the same time each iron filings piece will experience a magnetic torque:

$$
\tau=\mathbf{m} \times \mathbf{B}
$$

Where $m$ is the induced magnetic moment on each iron filings' piece and $B$ the generated magnetic field by the capacitor displacement current inside its air gap.

At the same time because the iron oxide layer the iron filings would be also be electrostatically charged therefore dipole interactions between them are possible and simultaneously they are also magnetic therefore will try to align both to the electric and magnetic field inside the air gap of the capacitor?

**What do you believe from the following patterns is more likely to resemble the 2D imprint (i.e. cross-section of field) from the iron filings left on the acrylic board after the experiment is finished and why?:**

**a)  Separated dots**

[image: a]

**b) Concentric rings**

[image: b]

**c) Spirals**

[image: c]

**d) Nothing from the above**

Comment: If I wanted to know, I'd do the experiment.

Comment: @JohnDoty So I guess this would be a novel tabletop experiment?

Comment: Actually now that I'm think of this experiment could be performed with a ferrolens magneto- optic flux sensor https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12044

Comment: Also we assume that the capacitor has relative high capacitance and is charged rapidly at KV level so that the generated magnetic field strength is non-trivial.

Comment: Very good related video (two parts): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWSz6TAsfH8 (part 1) and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC0exWbKaCc (part 2)